# problem in css issue 

Tags: html, css

i have div take css class

```
.headbg01
{
 background-image: url(../images/header_background01.jpg);
 border-left: #cccccc 1px solid;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width: 920px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 160px;
 border-right: #cccccc 1px solid;
}
```

its working great in ie

the problem is the bg image doesn't appear properly in firefox

here is the ie div view 
[alt text http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/3595/35520026.jpg](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/3595/35520026.jpg)
and here is the firefox div view
[alt text http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/950/31289427.jpg](http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/950/31289427.jpg)

i don't know whats wrong is it the height or what?
please i need some help

Comment: I suspect firefox doesn't like the ../ relative link.  but I'm not confident enough there to list that as an answer.

Comment: These two images don't say anything about what you think is wrong. Please describe the problem, and if possible link to an actual web page by way of example. If it's just a height issue, it may well be to do with adjacent/surrounding elements.

Comment: There's more going on here then just your CSS, see Pekka's comment.

Comment: Please post more code or a link to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to supply the background-position, try this:

```
.headbg01
{
  background: #fff url(../images/header_background01.jpg) no-repeat top left;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 920px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try declerating a strict doctype that should do the job

Answer (score 0):

It appears that one browser is stretching the height/width to fill the div without keeping the image's height/width ratio, whereas the other is using the image's dimensions to scale it properly.

Make sure your image and your div have the same dimensions, minus the 2 extra pixels for the left and right border.

EDIT:

After closer inspection, it appears that the top of the second image is being cut off.  Try specifying `background-position: top left;`.